# LocationListener function onLocationChanged() is not called

Tags: android

I want to track the user's current position. To do this, I implement the [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener) and its method `onLocationChanged`. However, this is never called when I activate route navigation in the emulator, for example. This function is also not carried out on the real device. What do I have to change for this to work?

```
class Map : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,LocationListener{

private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
private var builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

...

  builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)


    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult ?: return
            for (location in locationResult.locations){
                current = LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)
                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(current).title("Deine aktuelle Position"))
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(current))
            }

        }
    }

   val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)


}



private fun createLocationRequest() {
     locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(50000)
        .setIntervalMillis(10000)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .build()
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.getMainLooper())
}

override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
   Log.d("MAP", location.latitude.toString())
}
```

Comment: Are you requesting runtime location permission?  I don't see it in your code, and your start function is turning off the warning that you aren't checking for it.  Without requesting runtime permissions the location will not be turned on